# Find duplicate values by joining tables SQL server

Tags: sql-server, join, duplication, data-cleansing

Finding the duplicate values in the 'Item_Sales_Detail' table as NULL rows in the 'Sales' and 'Item' tables by joining three tables.

'Sales' table  (ID is primary key)

| ID | Invoice | Date | TotalAmount |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 00000000100001 | 02/02/2023 | 2000 |  |
| 20 | 00000000100002 | 02/02/2023 | 1500 |  |
| 30 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 18000 |  |

'Items' table (Sales_ID foreign key)

| ID | Sales_ID | Item_Code | Amount | Quantity | Total_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 22 | 2000 | 1 | 2000 |
| 2 | 20 | 35 | 1500 | 1 | 1500 |
| 3 | 30 | 44 | 5000 | 2 | 10000 |
| 4 | 30 | 14 | 8000 | 1 | 8000 |

'Item_Sales_Detail' table  (Sales_ID , Item_ID , Invoice are foreign keys)

| ID | Sales_ID | Item_ID | invoice | date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 00000000100001 | 02/02/2023 | 2000 |
| 2 | 10 | 1 | 00000000100001 | 02/02/2023 | 2000 |
| 3 | 20 | 2 | 00000000100002 | 02/02/2023 | 1500 |
| 4 | 30 | 3 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 5000 |
| 5 | 30 | 3 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 5000 |
| 6 | 30 | 3 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 5000 |
| 7 | 30 | 4 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 8000 |

In table "Item_Sales_Detail," invoice number 00000000100001 has 1 extra record as a duplicate, and invoice number 00000000100003 with Item_ID 3 has quantity 2 and an extra record entered; the total is now 3 records instead of 2.

My query :

```
SELECT Sales.Invoice,
       Items.Item_Code,
       Item_Sales_Detail.invoice,
       Item_Sales_Detail.date,
       Item_Sales_Detail.Amount
FROM Sales
INNER JOIN Items ON Sales.ID=Items.Sales_ID
INNER JOIN Item_Sales_Detail Items.ID= Item_Sales_Detai.Item_ID
```

Result

| Sales.Invoice | Items.Item_Code | Item_Sales_Detail.invoice | Item_Sales_Detail.date | Item_Sales_Detail.Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000000100001 | 22 | 00000000100001 | 02/02/2023 | 2000 |
| 00000000100001 | 22 | 00000000100001 | 02/02/2023 | 2000 |
| 00000000100002 | 35 | 00000000100002 | 02/02/2023 | 1500 |
| 00000000100003 | 44 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 5000 |
| 00000000100003 | 44 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 5000 |
| 00000000100003 | 44 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 5000 |
| 00000000100003 | 14 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 8000 |

Expected :

| Sales.Invoice | Items.Item_Code | Item_Sales_Detail.invoice | Item_Sales_Detail.date | Item_Sales_Detail.Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000000100001 | 22 | 00000000100001 | 02/02/2023 | 2000 |
| NULL | NULL | 00000000100001 | 02/02/2023 | 2000 |
| 00000000100002 | 35 | 00000000100002 | 02/02/2023 | 1500 |
| 00000000100003 | 44 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 5000 |
| 00000000100003 | 44 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 5000 |
| NULL | NULL | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 5000 |
| 00000000100003 | 14 | 00000000100003 | 02/02/2023 | 8000 |

Comment: Please, provide the sample data as CREATE  and INSERT statements. See [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Comment: I find duplicates by using GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate each instance of an item and match it against `Items.Quantity`.  Replace `Sales.Invoice` and `Items.Item_Code` with nulls where the number exceeds the quantity:

```
SELECT
  Invoice   = IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY isd.Item_ID ORDER BY isd.ID ASC) > i.Quantity, NULL, s.Invoice),
  Item_Code = IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY isd.Item_ID ORDER BY isd.ID ASC) > i.Quantity, NULL, i.Item_Code),
  isd.invoice,
  isd.date,
  isd.Amount
FROM
  dbo.Sales AS s
  INNER JOIN dbo.Items AS i ON s.ID = i.Sales_ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Item_Sales_Detail AS isd ON i.ID = isd.Item_ID
;
```

Comment: seems working fine but for item_code 14 with invoice 00000000100003 is shwoing null and it shouldn't be null

Comment: @MohammadBastan: For the item_code 14 in your example, no, it shouldn't, and I don't believe it does return a null there. The implementation is according to the requirements. On the other hand, I do admit that I didn't test my query. If you could provide a [test setup for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-), I'd be able to tune the query for you.

Comment: here it is https://dbfiddle.uk/udPtiNRQ

Comment: @MohammadBastan: Thank you.  The dbfiddle setup for which you've posted the link has a small but crucial difference from the setup in your question. That difference is the reason why you are not getting the expected result.  In the question, the row `ID=7` in `Item_Sales_Detail` has the `Item_ID` of `4`.  But in your dbfiddle setup, table `Item_Sales_Detail` has no row with `Item_ID=4`. The row 7 has `Item_ID=3`, which is correctly returned with nulls. Here's the [fixed setup](https://dbfiddle.uk/6xA8erlX), and the output is as expected. So the code works correctly, the error was in the data.